# Magento 1 vs Magento 2. Difference between solutions offered by Magento 1 and Magento 2 when is comes to web APIs

Tags: magento2, magento-1, integration, webapi

- **Specific on the area of web APIs.**
- Does Magento 2 offer something that Magento 1 does not.
- Are there any problems with Magento 1 Web APIs that Magento 2 has fixed
- What are the main differences between Magento 1 Web APIs and Magento 2 Web APIs

I've read the docs found here, found no obvious (or any other for that matter) differences

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web-based APIs (REST and SOAP) is fully improved in Magento 2. In M2, Using Service Contract API and web both are using the same functionality to access any resource. You can check [Architectural diagrams](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/archi_perspectives/arch_diagrams.html) to get more understanding about the flow.

You can also check [M2 overview of the Web API](https://inviqa.com/blog/magento-2-tutorial-overview-web-api) blog post.

**Some Major difference Between M1 API and M2 API:**

[image]

**Source:** [inviqa: Magento 2 tutorial: an overview of the Web API Post](https://inviqa.com/blog/magento-2-tutorial-overview-web-api)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the resources provided. One question only. How sure are you about "No unauthenticated access allowed" in M1? Looking through the docs here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html the anonymous level is stated.

Comment: @vitoriodachef sorry I don't have idea about this as in M1 I didn't work on API